# Login using derby database for web app (netbeans)

Tags: java, html, servlets, netbeans, derby

I'm trying to log in using data from a **derby database**, I set up but the `servlet 'loginservlet'` doesn't seem to be picking up the database. Is there a problem with my  code?

> Code from the loginservlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author billemerson
 */
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet  {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException { 
 try 
 {
     Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HOUSEPLANTSIRELAND","houseplant","pass");
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM HOUSEPLANT.USERDATA WHERE EMAIL=? AND PASSWORD=?");
        String EMAIL = req.getParameter("email");
        String PASSWORD = req.getParameter("password");
        ps.setString(4,EMAIL);
        ps.setString(5,PASSWORD);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {           
            res.sendRedirect("adminhome.jsp");   
        }
        else {
            res.sendRedirect("index.html");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());           
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter number is the problem. Your sql excerpt:

> WHERE EMAIL=? AND PASSWORD=?

`PreparedStatement` parameters are counted from 1. The first question mark is 1, second is 2, and so on. So the code will be:

```
    ps.setString(1,EMAIL);
    ps.setString(2,PASSWORD);
```

Comment: is this the the case if the email and password arent the first variables in the database e.g the way the data is saved is 'ID, firstname, lastname, email, password'

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException this error is after coming up now

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`

Comment: i changed my code but its still bringing up the error : HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: what do you mean by stack trace?

Comment: This will give the basics: http://www.codejava.net/java-core/exception/understanding-exception-stack-trace-in-java-with-code-examples

Comment: public Connection getConnection() {

        loadJDBCDriver();

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        String strUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HOUSEPLANTS1";
        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle.getStackTrace());
        }

        return dbConnection;

    }

Comment: that is the stack trace i have